# How to reference the close of a specific bar for a conditional character plot in Pinescript (tradingview)?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I can’t figure out how to store and refer to a specific bar's closing price in order to plot a countdown when two conditions are met.

Please see my image for a description of what I’m trying to achieve.

[image]

```
//bar1 starts the sequence and a “1” is plotted above bar 1 when the following simple condition is met:

bar1 = close > close[1]

//once the condition for bar1 is satisfied, bar2 must close above its prior bar’s close (close[1]) and bar2 must close above bar1’s close. When this happens, a 2 is plotted above bar2.

bar2 = close > close[1] and close > bar1’sclose

// once the condition for bar2 is satisfied, bar3 must close above its prior bar’s close (close[1]) and bar 3 must close above bar2’s close. When this happens, a 3 is plotted above bar3.

bar3 = close > close[1] and close > bar2’sclose

//This loop the restarts, with the next bar where close > close[1] labeled as 1 and so on down the line.

//Note the X in the image for reference only, which shows a failed bar3 where the close > close[1] but the close < bars2’sclose; therefore a 3 isn't plotted.
```

Any tips please?

Thank you!!

I know how to plot the characters when the conditions are met I just don't know how to reference/store a specific bar's close as a variable for later reference. I tried using valuewhen to no avail.